# Angular: Using a function as a custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to filter ng-repeat, but am trying to use a function rather than an actual filter to filter the data.  I was under the impression that something like this would work

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in dataObj| filter:dataFilter">
```

And define dataFilter as a scope function.

```
    $scope.dataFilter = function (item) {
        console.log(item);
        return false
    };
```

Obviously the filter is just a test, which I would have expected to log the items and also return false for everything (thus displaying nothing after the filter is done).  However the filter doesn't seem to even be called because the log doesn't fire.  I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.  I want to try this method of using a function rather than an actual filter which needs to be injected.

---

**Update with more code**

**Directive**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('test')
    .directive('myDirective', MyDirective);

function MyDirective() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'test.html',
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        controller: 'MyController',
        "scope":{
            "dataObj" : '='
        }
    };
}
})();
```

**Controller**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('test')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MyController($scope) {

    $scope.dataFilter = function (item) {
        console.log(item);
        return false
    };

}
})();
```

**test.html**

```
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in dataObj | filter:dataFilter">
            <td>{{key}}</td>
            <td>{{(value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The above code does not call the dataFilter function at all. It appears that I have to call it as a function and possibly send it a parameter.  For example if I do:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in dataObj | filter:dataFilter()">
```

The console will log "undefined" a number of times equal to the number of items in dataObj.  (obvious since there was no parameter passed in).  But what is perplexing is that even though I didn't pass any data in or do any real filtering, i would still expect that the view should not print out any data at all because the dataFilter() is returning false (as a test of course).  Yet all the data is printed out in .

**Overall issue**

The function as a filter doesn't seem to work at all, even when actually called.  I expected that a function that returns false should mean that the ng-repeat will "filter" (skip) that particular item.

The second issue is how to actually send the current "item" to the dataFilter function.  I have tried sending key and value, but neither of them are defined.

Comment: are you sure that dataObj has values ? If you take the filter off it changes anything ?

Comment: you can't sort or filter an object

Comment: @LucasRoselli yes the dataObj has values, but the filter/function seems to never be invoked at all.  One would think that if it were invoked, I would not see any data at all right? (because it automatically just returns false). But I see all of the data, so it is as if its not getting called.  

Further details: this is in a directive, although that shouldn't matter. The dataFilter function is in the directive's controller.  Also one other detail is I am using angular 1.27

Comment: see your suppost code: http://jsfiddle.net/yu2q2Lnz/ it's been passedthe function, I really believe it's something else

Comment: And please show us you entire code, because now you said directives, I really believe your function dataFilter it's not on scope

Comment: I've updated to show more of the code.  I have to genericize the code so hopefully I didn't make any silly mistakes when renaming and removing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use the standard $filter service on an object, it **must** be an array - the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) is quite clear.  I am unsure why you are not getting an error like [this](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%22key%22%3A%22key%201%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22value%201%22%7D) - note the link gives an example of how to implement a custom filter than operates on an object, which is what you want.

Use ng-if, ng-switch etc. to control ng-repeat flow.  Your assumption regarding $filter results affecting ng-repeat iteration is misplaced.

Regardless of what some might say, it's totally OK to filter an object (as opposed to an array) but as noted above that **requires** a custom filter, which you state you don't want, so you're left with no solution given your requirements.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0snykyqe/1/) that is as good as it gets without a custom filter.  You **have** to supply an array.

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(item,result) in model | filter:myfilter"   
        ng-if="result">    
      <td>{{result.key}}=</td>
      <td>{{result.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note above for clarity it's (item,result) not (key,value).  Here's the code.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  // You cannot pass standard $filter an object.  It MUST be an array.
  var obj = {
    pi: 3.14,
    aqua: "teen",
    then: new Date(),
    hunger: "force",
  }
  $scope.model = [];

  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
      $scope.model.push({
        key: key,
        value: obj[key]
      })
  }

  $scope.myfilter = function(item, index) {
    console.log(item.key + " = " + item.value)
    if (index % 2 == 0)
      return undefined;
    return item;
  }
}]);
```